# connecting 2 monitors on dell lattitude E5430

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

I have **dell lattitude E5430** which has **an in-built HDMI slot (1) and VGA slot (1)**. I am trying to connect two monitors with these two slots.
I tried a couple of combinations -

**1-** Used HDMI to VGA converter and connected one monitor with it, and connected another monitor directly with the in-built VGA slot.

**Result -** The laptop identifies both the screens but do not display on both, meaning, screen 2 or 3 works at a time only.

**2-** I connected one monitor with an HDMI port directly and connected another one with VGA port.

**Result-** This combination also did not work.

**Can you suggest what should work? and how should it work?**

Answer (score 0):

Config 2 should work fine

I don't know which desktop you used. Me I used mate, so I can use mate-display-setting for setting it.. I don't know application name with other desktop.
You can look here :
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/675136-how-to-configure-displaylink-displays-on-ubuntu

In command line you can try something like that :

Get monitor list :

xrandr --listmonitors

Config a monitor :

```
Set the resolution: xrandr --output DVI-1-0 --mode 1680x1050
Set the position: xrandr --output DVI-1-0 --left-of DVI-2-1
```

or
French sorry : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/xrandr

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 1680x1050 --primary
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1280x1024 --right-of DP-2
```

BR